# How to add only new tables to existing database with EF core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0

We are using EF core and have a situation which can be described as below

We need to be able to create only new tables which are needed by the application (i.e. a bot built using aspnet core) if they do not exist in the database. Also **note that** there are certain tables which exists in the same database and the application intends to consume them, however since those are created from external process - the bot shouldn't be creating those.

We are aware that we can consume already existing tables in the database using scaffolding method in ef core and also have set of migrations ready for tables which needs to be created but we are unsure if it is the right way to do it specially when on-boarding new a tenant.

Assuming that even if we get everything working on the dev database tenant, how do we plan to on-board new tenants or prepare different databases which are also going to have some tables and ensure that the application creates only new tables and can also consume existing tables?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if your existing tables are *completely* segregated from your code-first tables. When using code-first, anything the context is responsible for will be created. As such, even if you just have a foreign key to one of the existing table entities, that context will attempt to create that table along with everything else. In short, any entity representing an existing table cannot have any contact with any code-first entity. Period.

However, your design is flawed to begin with. Tenancy should be handled with different databases. If there's some set of tables that they'll all need to reference, that can be a separate database connection. If there's some set of tables that all will have, but don't necessary need access to each other's data there, then those tables should just be created in every tenant database. No self-respecting customer would *ever* utilize a service that utilizes single database tenancy. As an Enterprise customer myself, the minute I found out you did that would be the same minute you got shown the door.